# How to read property names on related list

Tags: c#

With these models:

```
public class Course
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<CourseEvent> CourseEvents { get; set; }
}

public class CourseEvent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CourseId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

...and this method:

```
private void WritePropertyNames(object obj)
{
    foreach (var item in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " => " + item.GetValue(obj, null));
    }
}
```

...I can get the property names and values on any object provided:

```
var course = new Course { Title = "My course", CourseEvents = new List<CourseEvent>() { new() { StartDate = DateTime.Today }, new() { StartDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) } } };

WritePropertyNames(course);
```

But how do I get the related `CourseEvents` property names and values too? I've tried this, but that's not right:

```
foreach (var item2 in obj.GetType().GetProperty("CourseEvents").GetType().GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(item2.Name + " => " + item2.GetValue(obj, null));
}
```

Comment: Assuming `t` is a constructed generic type you can extract the type parameters from `t.GenericTypeArguments`

Comment: pretty simple ... check if `item.GetValue(obj, null)` is `IEnuemrable` (but not string) and if it is, instead writing, enumerate and call `WritePropertyNames` for every element ...

Comment: Just write a `ToString` overload. don't use reflection, it's costly. Lazy programmers make bad programmers.

Comment: yeah ... `ToString` is the way ... especially now, when we have source generators (google "source generator C# ToString" there should be pleanty examples and implementations)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at the `ToString` way, but for now the provided answer fits the purpose of finding out if what I'm trying to do is doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be ugly and not optimal and won't work for all the cases (quickly wrote it just to demonstrate the idea)

So you could check if property is Generic by `item.PropertyType.IsGenericType`, you could also check if it type implements IEnumerable `typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(item.PropertyType)`. Then you could get the underlying type using `item.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]`. Then it basically becomes your logic that you have - you iterating over objects and getting props as you already have

```
private static void WritePropertyNames(object obj)
{
    foreach (var item in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if(item.PropertyType.IsGenericType && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(item.PropertyType))
        {
            var innerProps = item.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0].GetProperties();
            foreach(var innerItem in item.GetValue(obj, null) as IEnumerable)
            {
                foreach(var innerProp in innerProps)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " => " + innerProp.Name + " => " + innerProp.GetValue(innerItem, null));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " => " + item.GetValue(obj, null));
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not need to check if `item.PropertyType.IsGenericType` https://dotnetfiddle.net/yo9eIN

Comment: Agree, can be done that way also